# Developing applications for Apple TV

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

I am an iPhone developer interested in developing applications for Apple TV.
Does Apple provide a SDK for the Apple TV?
If I can develop for the Apple TV how do I install the SDK on my Apple TV?

Comment: Which version of Apple TV ? The current one (very small) or the older, larger one ?

Comment: Is it possible in any of the versions?? Either of the version is fine.

Comment: I believe there was a jailbreak for the original Apple TV which allowed you to run your own code etc - I'm not sure about the new one.

Answer (score 5):

### tvOS

The new Apple TV ([4th generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_TV#4th_generation_2), 2015) runs [tvOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TvOS). It features an AppStore, allowing third-party app developers to release their own apps on the platform. tvOS is based 95% on iOS 9 and the rest being adaptions to optimize it for the TV.

### Creating tvOS apps with the tvOS SDK.

tvOS leverages many of the same frameworks, technologies, and concepts that you are already familiar developing with for iOS.

1. To learn more about tvOS start with [tvOS for developers](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/).
2. You need tools - SDKs and other useful software is [here](https://developer.apple.com/tvos/download/).
3. Check out [tvOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/navigation/) -  browse documentation and code samples.
4. When you got stuck ask on stackoverflow, tag your question with tvOS tag. You might also find help on [Apple Developer Forum](https://forums.developer.apple.com/community/app-frameworks/tvos-sdk).
5. Finally, there is lots of tvOS tutorials, just google [them](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=tvos%20tutorial).

Answer (score 4):

There is currently no way to develop applications specifically for Apple TV.  You can, however, write an iOS (iPhone/iPad) app that leverages Apple TV as a display.  There are several games that do this already.  They allow you to output a display to the TV and have a different interface on the iOS device (like controls).

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a open source tool chain for making apps for Apple tv2/3 but remember that Apple officially doesn't support it.

I don't know what Apple think about iOS developers that uses this toolchain and release apps (like fire core does).

And one more thing, your Apple TV must be Jailbroken in order to run these apps.

Have a look [here](https://github.com/tomcool420/) for code examples

Answer (score 0):

Apple has released new SDK named as TVos for developing AppleTV Applications.
You can easily develop Apps on Swift,Objective C and TVML & TVJS(JS and XML based languages only for Apple TV)

Answer (score 0):

Since the question is from 2011, I will assume that you were asking about the Apple TV 2. Apple has to invite companies to develop apps for the 2nd and 3rd generation Apple TVs. With the 4th generation Apple TV, anybody with a developer account could make apps for the Apple TV. [Check here for more info](http://developer.apple.com/tvos)